# Xamarin.Forms assembly references

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms application for Android and iOS. The pcl project grew quite a lot and has many nuget packages installed like FluentValidation, SQlite and Newtonsoft.Json. The platform specific projects only have a few lines of code like custom renderer and stuff. The only references they have, is SQlite.

Now this works just fine when compiling for Android. However, when trying to build for iOS, I get an error -> Can not resolve reference (`System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll`).

My question is not specific to this dll, furthermore I'd like to know how it really works. I was assuming, I can install whatever package I want into the pcl project. Is there a limitation? Do the packages have to be compatible with Xamarin.iOS / Xamarin.Android? How am I able to track, where the dll actually comes from?

Why does it work in Android but not in iOS?

Comment: As far as I know, `System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll` is a native C++ library and is Win32 based only, thus you should not be referencing it in either of your Android or iOS app and not referenced in your PCL library. I would look for the bad reference and remove it (and/or find want package you installed in is pulling it as a package reference.

Comment: @SushiHangover That's the problem. I'm not aware of using the reference anywhere in my solution. How do I find this?

Comment: On OS-X/Linux you could do "find . -name "*.dll" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -I % ikdasm -assemblyref "%" | grep "Name="" from within your package directory to list all the ref'd assemblies. On Windows, you can use `Ildasm.exe` (For usage, consult:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx) AsmSpy, using the `--all` option also works well on Windows : https://github.com/mikehadlow/AsmSpy

Comment: @SushiHangover I tried using AsmSpy. Now I don't really know what to do with the output. Sure, there is the dll in my bin folder. But I still don't know why..

Comment: Search all the *other* `.dll`s to see which one is referencing it and if the one found is not a direct package reference, keep searching backwards till you find the root assembly.

Comment: @SushiHangover The wrapper doesn't appear anywhere else. Just the System.EnterpriseServices.dll, which is being referenced by System and mscorlib.. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are limitations between the platforms. The different assemblies and/or nuget-packages you use in the PCL-project, need to be comaptible for the platforms you are targeting.

The reason is quite simple: When you build your iOS-project, the PCL project is also building for the iOS target, and therefore the assemblies need to be compatible. The assemblies are just a subset.

> Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, and Xamarin.Mac all ship with over a
>   dozen assemblies. Just as Silverlight is an extended subset of the
>   desktop .NET assemblies, Xamarin platforms is also an extended subset
>   of several Silverlight and desktop .NET assemblies.

When you want to use an assembly, which is only compatible for android, then add it in the android-project and not in the PCL project.

You can find a list with [supported assemblies over the platforms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/#Supported_Assemblies) on the Xamarin Developer page.

On this list you can see, that `System.EnterpriseServices.dll` is only available for android and not for iOS. Additionaly you cand find some limitations using SQLite/`System.Data` on the iOS platforms on [this page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/system.data/#Missing_Functionality).